# Finding the closest number downward to a different number from an array

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, numbers

Example: I have an array like this: `[0,22,56,74,89]` and I want to find the closest number downward to a different number. Let's say that the number is `72`, and in this case, the closest number down in the array is `56`, so we return that. If the number is `100`, then it's bigger than the biggest number in the array, so we return the biggest number. If the number is `22`, then it's an exact match, just return that. The given number can never go under 0, and the array is always sorted.

I did see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3561275/using-jquery-how-would-i-find-the-closest-match-in-an-array-to-a-specified-num) but it returns the closest number to whichever is closer either upward or downward. I must have the closest one downward returned, no matter what.

How do I start? What logic should I use?

Preferably without too much looping, since my code is run every second, and it's CPU intensive enough already.

Comment: And the array is always sorted?

Comment: @Bergi Yes it is, edited question to reflect that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use a [binary search](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_algorithm) for that value. Adapted from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14370245/1048572):

```
function index(arr, compare) { // binary search, with custom compare function
    var l = 0,
        r = arr.length - 1;
    while (l <= r) {
        var m = l + ((r - l) >> 1);
        var comp = compare(arr[m]);
        if (comp < 0) // arr[m] comes before the element
            l = m + 1;
        else if (comp > 0) // arr[m] comes after the element
            r = m - 1;
        else // arr[m] equals the element
            return m;
    }
    return l-1; // return the index of the next left item
                // usually you would just return -1 in case nothing is found
}
var arr = [0,22,56,74,89];
var i=index(arr, function(x){return x-72;}); // compare against 72
console.log(arr[i]);
```

Btw: Here is a [quick performance test](http://jsperf.com/test-a-closest-number-function/3) (adapting the one from @Simon) which clearly shows the advantages of binary search.

Comment: A binary search would be the best you could do.  It would return your value in O(log n) although seeing as you didn't realize .grep is a loop in and of itself and that this problem can't be done without a loop of some sort then it is easy to see why you didn't realize this.

Comment: Wow, even faster? Thanks! In this case performance matters a lot to me so the shorter it takes to run is better :)

Comment: @DJDavid98: Of course, since it's `O(log n)` :-) Yet you might notice the effect only for big arrays, the one in the test has 1000 items.

Comment: Nice solution :), but note that the binary search is faster as the array gets bigger (in your case size of 1000 random numbers), while a straight forward loop is better with smaller arrays like 10 or 20. See http://jsperf.com/test-a-closest-number-function/4. So the OP should evaluate which loop to take for his case.

Comment: Btw: should give aquinas some credit for he's already given the binary search solution and I think extending the prototype is a pretty good idea ;).

Comment: @Simon: If you had only 10 or 20 items in your array, you would not need to care about performance - the test runs still millions of times per second

Comment: Of course, but if you take an array with a size of 5 like the OP's example, then the straight forward loop is 100% faster than a binary search after all (updated the jsperf #4) and it's still faster up to an array size of 20, beyond that the binary search starts to beat a straight forward loop. And as he pointed out: performance matters :).

Answer (score 5):

```
var theArray = [0,22,56,74,89];
var goal = 56;
var closest = null;

$.each(theArray, function(){
  if (this <= goal && (closest == null || (goal - this) < (goal - closest))) {
    closest = this;
  }
});
alert(closest);
```

jsFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/UCUJY/1/

Answer (score 2):

Here's a solution without jQuery for more effiency. Works if the array is always sorted, which can easily be covered anyway:

```
var test = 72,
    arr = [0,56,22,89,74].sort(); // just sort it generally if not sure about input, not really time consuming

function getClosestDown(test, arr) {
  var num = result = 0;

  for(var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    num = arr[i];
    if(num <= test) { result = num; }
  }

  return result;
}
```

Logic: Start from the smallest number and just set `result` as long as the current number is smaller than or equal the testing unit.

Note: Just made a little [performance test](http://jsperf.com/test-a-closest-number-function) out of curiosity :). Trimmed my code down to the essential part without declaring a function.

Answer (score 2):

```
Array.prototype.getClosestDown = function(find) {            
    function getMedian(low, high) {
       return (low + ((high - low) >> 1));
    }

    var low = 0, high = this.length - 1, i;  

    while (low <= high) {
     i = getMedian(low,high);
     if (this[i] == find) { 
         return this[i]; 
     }        
     if (this[i] > find)  { 
         high = i - 1;
     }
     else  { 
         low = i + 1;
     }
  }  
  return this[Math.max(0, low-1)];
}

alert([0,22,56,74,89].getClosestDown(75));
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's an ES6 version using reduce, which OP references. Inspired by this answer [get closest number out of array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8584902/get-closest-number-out-of-array#answer-19277804)

lookup array is always sorted so this works.

```
const nearestBelow = (input, lookup) => lookup.reduce((prev, curr) => input >= curr ? curr : prev);
const counts = [0,22,56,74,89];
const goal = 72;
nearestBelow(goal, counts); // result is 56.
```

Not as fast as binary search (by a long way) but better than both loop and jQuery grep https://jsperf.com/test-a-closest-number-function/7

Answer (score 0):

As we know the array is sorted, I'd push everything that asserts as less than our given value into a temporary array then return a pop of that.

```
var getClosest = function (num, array) {
    var temp = [],
        count = 0,
        length = a.length;

    for (count; count < length; count += 1) {

        if (a[count] <= num) {
            temp.push(a[count]);
        } else {
            break;
        } 
    }

    return temp.pop();
}

getClosest(23, [0,22,56,74,89]);
```

Comment: If you only care about the last value, why don't you just have a variable that holds that value? i.e., instead of `temp.push(a[count]);` just do: `currVal = a[count];` then `return currVal;`.

Answer (score 0):

Here is edited from @Simon.
it compare closest number before and after it.

```
var test = 24,
arr = [76,56,22,89,74].sort(); // just sort it generally if not sure about input, not really time consuming

function getClosest(test, arr) {
  var num = result = 0;
  var flag = 0;
  for(var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    num = arr[i];
    if(num < test) {
      result = num;
      flag = 1;
    }else if (num == test) {
      result = num;
      break;
    }else if (flag == 1) {
      if ((num - test) < (Math.abs(arr[i-1] - test))){
        result = num;
      }
      break;
    }else{
      break;
    }
  }
  return result;
}
```