# JavaScript, best way to find the index interval in an array with given number

Tags: javascript, arrays, algorithm

I'm not sure if I describe the question right, So I'll give a simple example.
Let's say I have an array:

```
var array = [0, 1.1, 2, 2.4, 4, 4.6, 5];
```

Given a number, 2.1
I want to find what index interval does it fall in. 
For this question, the answer will be 2,3.
Currently I have two ideas for this, first one is simple but definitely very slow, which is loop through the whole array and find where array[i-1] is less than 2.1 and array[i] is greater than 2.1.
Another way is, add 2.1 to the array, sort the array in ascending order, the answer will be the index of 2.1, and this index - 1.
Any other better suggestions?

Comment: the array is always sorted?

Comment: If the input array is alway sorted, then you can do a *binary search*, which takes O(log n) time unlike linear search which takes O(n). If not, the latter is the best you can do

Comment: Can you guarantee the order? Or could it be `arr = [1,1, 0, 4.6, 2]`?

Comment: Looking through the array will definitely be faster than adding to it, sorting it, and then finding the index of the entry you added.

Comment: The array is sorted in ascending order already

Comment: Sort the array and use the solution that you call "very slow". Only if you run into performance issues go for the binary search. Don't do premature optimization!

Comment: @neuhaus: I'd call that an answer.

Comment: I see, thanks for the advice @neuhaus

Comment: Have a look at [this implementation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14370245/1048572)

Comment: @MaXon, it is working my method for you ?

Comment: @Alexandru-IonutMihai I used neuhaus's way

Answer (score 2):

You would do a binary search:

```js
function binarySearch(array, el) {
    var m = 0;
    var n = array.length - 1;
    while (m <= n) {
        var k = (n + m) >> 1;
        var cmp = el - array[k];
        if (cmp > 0) {
            m = k + 1;
        } else if(cmp < 0) {
            n = k - 1;
        } else {
            return [k, k + 1];
        }
    }
    return [n, n+1];
}

var range = binarySearch([0, 1.1, 2, 2.4, 4, 4.6, 5], 2.3);

console.log(range);
```

The above code:

- Assumes that the array elements are all different and sorted ascending
- Returns a pair of indexes `[i, i+1]`
- Returns the pair of indexes such that `array[i] <= el < array[i+1]`
- If the given value is outside the range of the array, the output will be `[-1, 0]` when it is lower than the first array value, or `[n-1, n]` when it is greater than the last array value (`n` being the array's length).
- Has a *O(log(n))* time complexity.

Answer (score 0):

That can be achieved using `binary insert` algorithm.

Complexity:

It is in `best` case **O(1)** and in worst case **O(N)**. Even if the `Binary Insert` in itself is only `O(log(N))`, the `O(N)` comes from the insert which will always be `O(N)` in the worst case if you insert a value at the beginning – you would have to push the rest of the values `(N)` to the end.

For instance, `O(n)` will be when you want to push `4` in follow array: `let array=[3,6,9,10,20,21,23,24,26]`

It takes `O(log(N))` for search and `O(n)` for add.

How binary insert works:
[image]

```js
var array = [0, 1.1, 2, 2.4, 4, 4.6, 5];
function binaryInsert(value, array, startVal, endVal){

 var length = array.length;
 var start = typeof(startVal) != 'undefined' ? startVal : 0;
 var end = typeof(endVal) != 'undefined' ? endVal : length - 1;
 var m = start + Math.floor((end - start)/2);
 
 if(length == 0){
  array.push(value);
  return;
 }

 if(value > array[end]){
  array.splice(end + 1, 0, value);
  return;
 }

 if(value < array[start]){
  array.splice(start, 0, value);
  return;
 }

 if(start >= end){
  return;
 }

 if(value < array[m]){
  binaryInsert(value, array, start, m - 1);
  return;
 }

 if(value > array[m]){
  binaryInsert(value, array, m + 1, end);
  return;
 }
}
let number=2.1;
binaryInsert(number, array,0,array.length);
console.log(array.toString());
let index=array.indexOf(number);
console.log(index-1,index);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do using simple quicksort-style insertion function

```
var array = [0, 1.1, 2, 2.4, 4, 4.6, 5];
var element = 2.1;
function insert(element, array) {
  array.splice(locationOf(element, array) + 1, 0, element);
  return array;
}

function locationOf(element, array, start, end) {
  start = start || 0;
  end = end || array.length;
  var pivot = parseInt(start + (end - start) / 2, 10);
  if (end-start <= 1 || array[pivot] === element) return pivot;
  if (array[pivot] < element) {
    return locationOf(element, array, pivot, end);
  } else {
    return locationOf(element, array, start, pivot);
  }
}

console.log(insert(element, array));
```